# Logic within $(window).scroll() listener only changes value once. Never increases each time as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom-events

I have a short block of jQuery that is supposed update a count of table rows after an ajax call. This ajax call occurs once the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the page. The logic works the first time you reach the bottom, but after every subsequent time, the value is stuck. I cannot figure out why.

The jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
     //If typing in search field, don't listen for scroll event
     if($('#search_server_ip_input').val()) {
         e.preventDefault();
     } else {
         //else do the things
         let windowHeight = $(window).height();
         let documentHeight = $(document).height();
         let windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
         let row = Number($('#unused_row').val());
         let allcount = Number($('#unused_all').val());
         let rowperpage = 200;
         let countertext = $('#counter_text');
         let url = 'includes/search_ajax/list-unused-server-addresses.php';
         let tablerow = $('.table-row');


         if (windowScrollTop + windowHeight === documentHeight) {
              //Add 200 more to the value of row
             row += rowperpage;
             $(countertext).text('Showing ' + row + ' out of ' + allcount + ' results');
              if (row >= allcount) {
                 row = allcount;
                 $(countertext).text('Showing ' + row + ' out of ' + allcount + ' results');
             }
             if (row <= allcount) {
                 console.log('Reached if (row <= allcount)');
                 $(row).val(row);
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'post',
                     url: url,
                     data: {row: row},
                     success: function (data) {
                         //Show 200 additional rows of table
                         $('.table-row:last').after(data).show().fadeIn('slow');
                         //Update the text
                         $(countertext).text('Showing ' + row + ' out of ' + allcount + ' results');
                      }
                 })
             }

         }
     }
 })
```

MySQL logs show the same thing, so I know the value being passed in the ajax call is incorrect after the first time. It should be `LIMIT 600,200`, but it's still `LIMIT 400,200`:

```
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 200,200
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 400,200
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 400,200
```

The 3rd query should be 1`600,200`, but it remains 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the value of row was not being updated after the first time you reach the bottom of the page. So, I created a separate php file that retrieved a static value of 200 rows on the first button click. This php file was called in a new function. It was identical to the original ajax function, except there was no `data:{row:row}` portion. Instead of having the value of `$row` be `$_POST['row']`, I just made it 200:

First button click, called new function:

```
$('#server_unused_ip_btn').on('click', function() {
   //getUnused(row);
   getUnused(); //<-- No parameter this time
});
```

In the new version of the function that is called, I assigned the value of `row` being sent to the number of rows in the table instead, like so:

```
function getUnused() {
    $('input').not("input[type='hidden']").val('');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/search_ajax/get-unused-server-addresses.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#server_result_table tbody').html(data);
            let row = $('#server_result_table tr').not('thead tr').length; //<-- Here is how row is calculated now
            $('#unused_row').val(row); //<-- Now give the hidden input the new value
            $('#counter_text').text('Showing '+ row + ' out of <?php echo $allcount; ?> results'); //<-- Correctly update the text with new value of row
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: '+error);
        }
    })
}
```

Now my MySQL queries reflect the change has corrected it:

```
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 200,200
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 400,200
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 600,200
SELECT * FROM network_servers where (ping_response = 'N' and mac_address = 'n/a') ORDER BY INET_ATON(ip_address) LIMIT 800,200
```

So basically, in short, the initial button click executes a query that gets a static value of 200, then when you scroll to the bottom of the page, **that's** when the new value is sent via ajax by counting the number of rows present. This is working unless someone offers a better solution, which I will gladly accept.